# Google Authenticator passwords duplicated somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, java, python, google-authenticator, authenticator

I'm trying to know if this is possible at all. So far it doesn't look that great. Let's imagine I wanted to list all my current Google Authenticator passwords somewhere. That list would update once there's a new set. Is this possible at all?

I remember back when Blizzard made their authenticator. You would basically have to enter the recovery key/password from their app into a program, which could then show your authenticator on the screen and on your phone or physical device (yeah they sold those). I imagine they used TOTP just like Google Authenticator does.

So my real question is: I have my x amount of Google Authenticator passwords, which refreshes every 30 seconds. Can I pull these out and show them in another program? Java? Python? Anything? I assume "reverse engineering the algorithm" and brute forcing the keys (like grab 100 keys and work out the next key) would be impossible, as these are server-client based.. right?

Comment: (Not speaking to the feasibility of this, since I have no idea if there's an API or some such) But this seems like it totally defeats the purpose of the authenticator.

Comment: @CollinD How so? It just moves it to a better platform basically.

Comment: One of the points of the authenticator's 2fa is that you must physically possess the device with authenticator on it (ie: Something You Have). By cloning this access to another device, you lose proof of access to the initial device. Moreover, who knows if the ultimate implementation of this enhancement will actually be secure?

Comment: @CollinD That's a fair assumption. Let's assume it's just for personal use and I'm fine having it stored on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

So I dug a little deeper. This, however, requires I disable and remove the current 2FA from my account.

1. Go disable/remove current 2FA
2. Go enable it again, but remember to grab the secret (it's listed somewhere in the request or on the page) and save it somewhere
3. Find any secret -> One time password "generator"

Now I have the secrets synced on my PC and on my phone. Pretty neat. Requires a lot of work, as I need to disable all my authenticators, but it does work actually.